# Android Places Autocomplete How to detect each time suggestions changed?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I know Google is charging per character sent, at each request. It's a large amount of expenditure . I need to detect each time suggestions data changed or input text changed for limit to use.
In swift I use this func

```
func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {

}
```

But I don't know how to do that with Android. I find tutorial documents here https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/widget/AutocompleteSupportFragment but I dont  see any method about Autocomplete Predictions

I tried this way but cannot

```
EditText inputSearch = autocompleteFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Google's Place Autocomplete is billed per [session](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/session-tokens), not per characters, provided you're using session tokens (which are strongly recommended to lower [costs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#new-payg)).

You can then watch for changes using `onPlaceSelected` as follows:

```
// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Or with `onActivityResult` using intents:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

Or programmatically:

```
  placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
     for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {
         Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPlaceId());
         Log.i(TAG, prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());
     }
  }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
     if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
         ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
         Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
     }
  });
```

Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I think it is not what I want to ask.
I am temporarily limiting the number of requests per day on Developer console

Comment: Oh alright, can you please clarify then what your question/problem is?